# bit.ly cname redirects - PHP

Tags: php, subdomain, bit.ly, tinyurl

I understand how using a full domain with an A record works (`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`), but when using a subdomain with **bit.ly**, they ask for it to point to **cname.bit.ly** - why dont subdomains just get pointed to the same IP address as normal domains and is there a difference in determining the referring sub-domain?

Comment: This is not making sense to me yet. Can you explain what "using a subdomain with bit.ly" means exactly? Do they run a dynamic DNS service?

Comment: Their website states: In order to complete this step of the setup process, you will need to make one of the following DNS changes:
Set a DNS A Record making your custom short domain point to 168.143.174.97 

-- or --

If you are using a subdomain for your custom short domain, set a CNAME in your DNS record that points your subdomain to cname.bit.ly.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused as to why subdomains have to point to cname.bit.ly instead of 168.143.174.97

Comment: It's easier, in the future, for bit.ly to change servers or IP addresses for services if their users specifiy a non-changing CNAME pointing to their DNS record... instead of an IP address.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it make sense to have normal domains point to a cname or hostname rather than an IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no difference having a hostname either as cname or A-Record. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] has nothing to do with that. Cname is *not* a http-redirect.

If you want to determine the host (as requested by the user via http/1.1) which was requested in using your script, use $_SERVBER['HTTP_HOST]